# Audio Works on Computer but not Phones

Tags: audio

I have recorded the video by [Simple Screen Recorder](https://vitux.com/record-your-screen-with-simple-screen-recorder-under-ubuntu/) in my Ubuntu OS by below setting :

[image]
[image]

But when I play the recorded video on the android phone the sound is not clear, although it works on the laptop.
So I guess it must be from the frame rate of audio compressing or its type (mp3 or ...)

If you like, you can see one sample of the video on [this video link](https://www.namasha.com/v/vooemZsh).

**Update 1:**

I guess my left mic of laptop is corrupted, so I have changed the recording mic volume in my OS and now it is working with below setting:

[image]

So if possible I like to know how it creates corrupted sound in android and if possible how can I edited the audio part of recorded video in my [Shutcut](http://shotcut.org) video editor by below audio setting:

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: What video player app do you use? Try e.g. VLC and MXPlayer to check if the audio works at all.

Comment: It is working in laptop (VLC Player), and  as I want to send to others for seeing in android it must be ok in default android video players, which the player does not important in android  OS.

Comment: Checking the video with different players will allow you to identify if there is a general problem or if this is just an incompatibility. Additionally you should check the values shown by VLC (on PC) or another media info tool if the created video really uses the codecs you have chosen. BTW: Isn't the quality 23 a bit high? May be just the bitrate is too high for the tested Android devices? Use https://jell.yfish.us/ videos to test the capabilities of your device.